# JavaScript function not working due to cached JS file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, cloudflare

I have a few JS files which I need on every page in my admin panel, like: functions.js, login.js, ...

I combine all those files (and minify them) into one file using gulp: admin.js

Two days ago, I have made a new function called "changeTicketStatus", but there's one problem: **cache**.

- Whenever someone visits my website, the new function **does not** work yet.
- When they visit http://website/js/admin.js manually in the browser, they **do** see the new function.
- When they check via sources (in chrome dev tools), they **do not** see the function.

Since we are using CloudFlare for caching, I thought this might be the problem, but we already purged all cache on CF and it is still not working.

The people who are trying to visit my website have already cleared their cache too. **It does work in private mode (incognito)**, so I guess it should be something cache related... I just think it's really weird that even after clearing their cache, the function's still not appearing in dev tools.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. I'm out of ideas, I really don't know how to fix this.

Kenny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a random querystring to end of include script

for example:

```
instead of <script src="app.js"></script>
use this <script src="app.js?v234123"></script>
```

This will solve your problem about caching.

Comment: This does indeed work, but why doesn't it work by clearing the cache?

Comment: My opinion is you are using CloudFlare and it uses own Caching system to serve pages faster. With clearing the cache you are clearing the cache of client browser. In fact this work but original source end user trying to reach is still have caching by CloudFlare. I hope this will clarify your questions.

Comment: I didn't use CF much so i don't have any more knowledge about situation sorry. You can try to add random querystring at least for now :)